# TKinter Python make only one cell larger

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently have this grid

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghbk0.jpg

I want to make it like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTnob.jpg

Would it be possible? Heres my code:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("TOMBOLA")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.config(bg="WHITE")
entry= Entry(root, width= 40)
entry.focus_set()
entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=25)
texto=Label(root, text="Introduce el nombre para agregar a la tómbola:", font=("Courier")).grid(column=0, row=0, padx=(10,0))

boton_ok=Button(root, text="OK", width=10, height=2)
boton_ok.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=(25,0))


listaindic = Label(root, text="Lista: ")
listaindic.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

display = Label(root, text="")
display.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky=E)

boton_sig=Button(root, text="INICIAR TOMBOLA").grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=1, pady=(0,15))

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you all so much

I tried making columnspan bigger, but didnt end well.

Comment: Please don't post links to code on another site. [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter relies on cells and rows to display widgets, without these there is no functionality. This being the case there is really no way of doing what you are asking in the first image. **Everything has to be in a cell**. So how I would try to fix your problem is by creating a `tkinter.Frame` and insert it into the cell you are trying to configure (1, 1). This creates another grid inside the frame so we can choose what to do with it. e.g: increasing the weight on the second column to make it seem much bigger.

```
newFrame = Frame(master=root)
newFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
newFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
newFrame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=3)

listaindic = Label(newFrame, text="Lista: ")
listaindic.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
```

This shows you how to create a basic frame, and putting the Label into the first cell.